# Dynamically update form id values using a loop

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form a field called **Name** and with a field's id as:

```
    'id_Name_set-0' on row 0
    'id_Name_set-1' on row 1
     etc...
```

'Name_set-0','Name_set-1' are set automatically when the rows are created.

I'm trying to autofill the **Name** field with the name entered on row 0.

My first approach was:

```js
    $('#id_Name_set-0').on('input',function(e){
        $('#id_Name_set-1').val(String($('#id_Name_set-0').val()));
    });

    $('#id_Name_set-0').on('input',function(e){
            $('#id_Name_set-1').val(String($('#id_Name_set-0').val()));
        });

    $('#id_Name_set-0').on('input',function(e){
            $('#id_Name_set-2').val(String($('#id_Name_set-0').val()));
        });
```

This works fine since i hard-coded the values 0,1,2...but i want to dynamically update those values using a loop.

Comment: _“but i want to dynamically update those values using a loop.”_ - then don’t let us stop you … Please go read [ask]. We expect you to show us what you tried and describe what your specific problem with it was - _not_ just to tell us what you “want”.

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com), [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) + a `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your inputs using `$('input[id^="id_Name_set-"]')`, get the total number of them, and then just skip the first (number 0) one in the loop.

```
var totalDivs = $('input[id^="id_Name_set-"]').length;

for(var i = 1; i < totalDivs; i++)
{
    $("#id_Name_set-" + i).val(i);
}
```

*Obviously adapt the above to your needs such as setting all the inputs to the value of the first input. It's only an example of how to achieve it.*

Comment: TOs? As far as I can see by your comment is you've misunderstood what is asked (or maybe me?)... going by the following "I'm trying to autofill the Name field with the name entered on row 0." I can only assume the OP wants to fill remaining inputs based on the first input where each input is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JQUERY` for this, first get all inputs and set `each` loop on it.

`this.id` will get the id of which input where use inputs.

```js
$("input").each(function(){
  $(this).on("input",function(){
    alert(this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1"/>
<input id="input2"/>
<input id="input3"/>
<input id="input4"/>
```